# $(window).scrollTop() less than $(document).height() - $(window).height()

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a jquery scroll event

```
var page = 0;
 $(document).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {//ajax feels when mouse scrolls
        page++;
        var parameters = { "page": page };
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Index")',
            data: parameters,
            success: function (data) {//success Case
                $("#ActivityRecords").append(data);
            }

        });
    }
});
```

and I want to call a controller function that call a LINQ take and skip operators

```
public ActionResult Index(int? page)
        {
            var skipRecords = (page != null ? page.Value : 0) * recordsPerPage;
            ActivitiesVM[] Activities = Rep.GetAll(recordsPerPage, skipRecords);
            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                return PartialView("_Activities", Activities);
            }
            string IDUsedInaddNewActivity = Rep.GetID();
            ViewData["ID"] = IDUsedInaddNewActivity;
            return View(Activities);
        }
```

and when I debug this line

```
 if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height())
```

I get the following

```
$(document).height() - $(window).height() = 1113-246 = 867
```

and
$(window).scrollTop() = 866.6666896254934

which means it remains 0.333311 to call the ajax request

What should I do to get this condition TRUE

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height())
```

Note that I use google chrome

Comment: Any margin/padding/border set on `body/html` element??? Can you post any MCVE?  EDIT: you should bind scroll event to `window` object, not `document` `$(window).on('scroll', handler);`

Comment: this page inherits from a layout that was a template and I used its _Layout and I customized somethings,
but I tried to solve this problem but I failed how I solve it ?
I changed the $(document).on('scroll', handler);